# channel is already closed due to channel error rabbitmq

Tags: java, rabbitmq

I am triying to develop a publish/subscribe system using RabbitMQ. The RabbitMQ server is in my laptop.
I have coded the Consumer and Producer Classes. The producer is connected correctly to the broker, but I have a **com.rabbitmq.client.ShutdownSignalException** when I run the consumer class.

My code is as follow. 
I have a Functions.class :

```
public class Functions {


public static String EXCHANGE_NAME = "exchange";

private static ConnectionFactory factory;

/**
 * Initialization for ConnectionFactory
 */
static {
    factory = new ConnectionFactory();
    factory.setAutomaticRecoveryEnabled(true);

    factory.setHost("localhost");

}


public static Connection createConnection() {
    try {
        return factory.newConnection();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return null;

    }
}}
```

Then the MyCosumer.java Class:

```
public class MyConsumer {

private Connection connection;
private Channel channel;
private String queueName = "consumer";

public MyConsumer() {

}


public void connect() throws IOException {
    connection = Functions.createConnection();
    channel = connection.createChannel();
    channel.exchangeDeclare(Functions.EXCHANGE_NAME, BuiltinExchangeType.TOPIC);
    channel.queueDeclare(queueName, true, false, false, new HashMap<String, Object>()).getQueue();

}

public void setRoutingKeys(String... keys) throws IOException {
    for (String bindingKey : keys) {
        channel.queueBind(queueName, Functions.EXCHANGE_NAME, bindingKey);
    }
}


public void clearRoutingKeys(String... keys) throws IOException {
    for (String bindingKey : keys) {
        channel.queueUnbind(queueName, Functions.EXCHANGE_NAME, bindingKey);
    }
}

public void recieveMessages() throws IOException {
    Consumer consumer = new DefaultConsumer(channel) {
        @Override
        public void handleDelivery(String consumerTag, Envelope envelope, AMQP.BasicProperties properties,
                byte[] body) throws IOException {
            String message = new String(body, "UTF-8");
            System.out.println(" [x] Received '" + envelope.getRoutingKey() + "':'" + message + "'");
        }
    };

    channel.basicConsume(queueName, true, consumer);

}
public void disconnect() throws IOException, TimeoutException {
    channel.close();
    connection.close();
}
```

}

And the MyProducer.java Class :

```
public class MyProducer {

private Connection connection;
private Channel channel;

public MyProducer() {

}


public void connect() throws Exception {
    connection = Functions.createConnection();
    channel = connection.createChannel();
    channel.exchangeDeclare(Functions.EXCHANGE_NAME, "topic");
}

public void sendMessage(String routingKey, String message) throws IOException {
    channel.basicPublish(Functions.EXCHANGE_NAME, routingKey, null, message.getBytes());
    System.out.println(" [x] Sent '" + routingKey + "':'" + message + "'");
}


public void disconnect() throws IOException, TimeoutException {
    channel.close();
    connection.close();
}}
```

The main classes are as follow :

the Producer main:

```
public class MainProducer {

public static String[] categorias = { "Beauty", "Drinks", "Diary", "Vegetable" };

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

    MyProducer productor = new MyProducer();
    productor.connect();
    send(productor, categorias[1], "Makeup", "Discount 20% in loreal lipstick");
    send(productor, categorias[0], "Soap", "2x1 in Herbal Essence soap");
    send(productor, categorias[0], "Makeup", "Discount 10% in l'ocitane lipstick");
    send(productor, categorias[0], "Loreal Makeup", "Discount 20% in loreal lipstick");
    productor.disconnect();
}

private static void send(MyProducer productor, String categoria, String producto, String mensaje) {
    String routingKey = "offers." + categoria + "." + producto;
    try {
        productor.sendMessage(routingKey, mensaje);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}}
```

THe consumer Main:

```
public class MainConsumer {

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    MyConsumer consumer = new MyConsumer();
    consumer.connect();
    consumer.setRoutingKeys("kern");
    consumer.recieveMessages();
}}
```

The obtained exception is :

```
Exception in thread "main" java.io.IOException
at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.AMQChannel.wrap(AMQChannel.java:124)
at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.AMQChannel.wrap(AMQChannel.java:120)
at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.AMQChannel.exnWrappingRpc(AMQChannel.java:142)
at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.ChannelN.queueDeclare(ChannelN.java:952)
at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.recovery.AutorecoveringChannel.queueDeclare(AutorecoveringChannel.java:333)
at main.MyConsumer.connect(MyConsumer.java:44)
at main.MainConsumer.main(MainConsumer.java:7)

Caused by: com.rabbitmq.client.ShutdownSignalException: channel error; protocol method: #method<channel.close>(reply-code=404, reply-text=NOT_FOUND - home node 'rabbit@souhaila-UX430UAR' of durable queue 'consumer' in vhost '/' is down or inaccessible, class-id=50, method-id=10)
at com.rabbitmq.utility.ValueOrException.getValue(ValueOrException.java:66)
at com.rabbitmq.utility.BlockingValueOrException.uninterruptibleGetValue(BlockingValueOrException.java:36)
at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.AMQChannel$BlockingRpcContinuation.getReply(AMQChannel.java:443)
at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.AMQChannel.privateRpc(AMQChannel.java:263)
at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.AMQChannel.exnWrappingRpc(AMQChannel.java:136)
... 4 more

Caused by: com.rabbitmq.client.ShutdownSignalException: channel error; protocol method: #method<channel.close>(reply-code=404, reply-text=NOT_FOUND - home node 'rabbit@souhaila-UX430UAR' of durable queue 'consumer' in vhost '/' is down or inaccessible, class-id=50, method-id=10)
at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.ChannelN.asyncShutdown(ChannelN.java:509)
at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.ChannelN.processAsync(ChannelN.java:340)
at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.AMQChannel.handleCompleteInboundCommand(AMQChannel.java:162)
at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.AMQChannel.handleFrame(AMQChannel.java:109)
at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.AMQConnection.readFrame(AMQConnection.java:643)
at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.AMQConnection.access$300(AMQConnection.java:47)
at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.AMQConnection$MainLoop.run(AMQConnection.java:581)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

Comment: Please indicate line # 44 in your `MyConsumer.java` file.